# Change class of Panel right before the click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the class before the animation starts/open/close the panel? Actually the class changes after the animation/panel is opened or closed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0b9jppve/

Actual code:

```
$('#accordion').find('.panel-default:has(".in")').addClass('panel-danger');

$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   $(e.target).closest('.panel-default').addClass(' panel-danger');
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   $(e.target).closest('.panel-default').removeClass(' panel-danger');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the events you're listening for. The events `hide.bs.collapse` and `show.bs.collapse` fire when the animation starts, `hidden.bs.collapse` and `shown.bs.collapse` fire on completion.

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   $(e.target).closest('.panel-default').addClass(' panel-danger');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   $(e.target).closest('.panel-default').removeClass(' panel-danger');
})
```

[**See this updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0b9jppve/1/)

Comment: yeah. I am just waiting the time limit. ;)